# Extracting Data From JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I need to know that how could i extract data if i have response like this

```
Object {cast: Object}
    cast: Array[5]
        0: Object
            text: "Select Any"
            value: "000"
            __proto__: Object
        1: Object
        2: Object
        3: Object
        4: Object
```

Same this pattern in remaining Object

Update 1

I have array like this

```
var response = {};
response = showData();
```

and when i `console.log(response)`
then in my console the above mention output will display
and when i tried `response.length` it shows me `undefined`

Update 2

```
function showData(){
    var foodSubCatagories1 = {};
    foodSubCatagories1.cast = _context.FoodGroup.forEach(function(FG)
    {
        $('#selectCatagoryFood').append('<option value="'+FG.FoodGroupID+'">'+FG.Description+'</option>');
}).then(function(){
    $('#selectCatagoryFood').selectmenu('refresh');
foodSubCatagories1.cast = [
{
    value: "000",
    text: "Select Any"
},
{
    value: "1",
    text: "Juice"
},
{
    value: "2",
    text: "Dairy"
},
{
    value: "3",
    text: "Farm"
},
{
    value: "4",
    text: "Custom"
}
];
return foodSubCatagories1.cast;
});
return foodSubCatagories1;
```

}

Comment: Loop through `obj.cast` and access `obj.cast[idx].text` etc

Comment: Object.cast? Have you tried that?

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey i updated my question please review it

Comment: @PSL  i updated my question please review it

Comment: done ,your array is subobject

Comment: `var response = {};` creates an object not an array. what does showData() look like? where's the code for that?

Comment: @b_dubb i updated question with `showData()` code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

```
    for ( var c in response.cast ) 
    {
    console.log ( c ); // array item 
  console.log ( c.text); //  item propery 
    }
```

Comment: Note: Using `for..in` with an `Array` [isn't typically recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea). And, `c` will be a key, not a value.